# Generating function for sequence $a_n = \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil $

Tags: generating-functions

In one of books for discrete mathematics i came across sum to calculate $$\sum_{k=0}^n \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$$ which was fairly easy, but this sum intrigued me what is generating function for $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil x^n $$ so from that i can easily calculate $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \sum_{k=0}^n \lceil \sqrt{k} \rceil $$

My attempt:

Our sequence looks like this $0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4 \dots$
We see, difference between adjancent positions is 0 or 1. Let's write it down: $0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, \dots$

First zero seems quite uncomfortable, so let's ignore it (but we will have to multiply final generating function by $x$).

So, now we deal with $1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, \dots$
Between adjancent ones there is: 0 zeros, then 2 zeros, then 4 zeros, 6 zeros and so on...

I can't really see some pattern here (how to pack zeros and ones in one sequence), i would really appreciate some hints or solutions to this, because it appears as really interesting problem. Cheers

Comment: Surely your series converges if $\left|x\right|<1$ because $\left\lceil \sqrt{n}\right\rceil <\sqrt{n}+1$ and $\sum_{n\geq1}\sqrt{n}x^{n}=\textrm{Li}_{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(x\right).$

Comment: @MarcoCantarini thanks for this comment, but we don't need to care about convergence of this generating function as long as we don't substitute any value for x.

Comment: Yes, it was only to consider how big can be the radius of convergence for the generating function ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the answer can only be written in terms of the Jacobi theta functions (or the like).  Specifically, we have

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil x^n
    & = x + 2x^2 + 2x^3 + 2x^4 + 3x^5 + 3x^6 + 3x^7 + 3x^8 + 3x^9 + \cdots \\
    & = (x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots) + (x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \cdots)
      + (x^5 + x^6 + x^7 + \cdots) + \cdots \\
    & = \frac{x}{1-x} + \frac{x^2}{1-x} + \frac{x^5}{1-x} + \cdots \\
    & = \frac{x}{1-x} (1 + x + x^4 + x^9 + x^{16} + \cdots) \\
    & = \frac{x}{1-x} \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k^2} \\
    & = \Bigl(\frac{x}{1-x}\Bigr) \Bigl(\frac{\vartheta_3(0, x) - 1}{2}\Bigr)
\end{align}
$$

Don't know if this helps you at all.

Comment: Fixed the final line of the result.  (ETA: Bleah, and also fixed some other minor typos throughout.)